# messed up java installation on mac

Tags: java, installation

I have probably removed some classes that I shouldn't have removed, because when I'm making a project in eclipse, everything works fine when I set my project to use java SE 1.5, but when I try to use version 1.6, it says the type 'java.lang.object' cannot be resolved. rerunning the java installation package doesn't wrk, how can I fix this?

the output of the ls command someone requested in the comments:

```
total 64
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    5 18 mrt 16:03 1.3 -> 1.3.1
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  102 14 jan  2008 1.3.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    5  5 sep  2010 1.4 -> 1.4.2
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 25 mrt  2010 1.4.1 -> 1.4
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel  272 23 jul  2009 1.4.2
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    5 18 mrt 16:03 1.5 -> 1.5.0
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel  272 23 jul  2009 1.5.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    5 18 mrt 16:03 1.6 -> 1.6.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   59 18 mrt 16:03 1.6.0 -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel  340 18 mrt 16:03 A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    1 18 mrt 16:03 Current -> A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 18 mrt 16:03 CurrentJDK -> 1.5
```

the java settings utility[image]

Comment: Please do a 'ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/' in terminal and post your output.

Comment: I am assuming you tried uninstalling before reinstalling?

Comment: doing that now.

Comment: Looks normal too me, you could register as an apple developer (it's free) and then get access to http://developer.apple.com/java/download/ where you can download java for reinstallation.

Comment: Btw, have you tried to change your java runtime with the /Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences.app ?

Comment: adding a screenshot of the utility.

Comment: hm... looks good too, try reinstallation or buy a new mac :-)

Comment: How do I actually uninstall it COMPLETELY before rerunning the installer, to force it to really reinstall evertything?

Comment: You could do a 'sudo rm -Rf /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/' however, since your java seems to be messed up anyway...

Comment: that's one of the things I hate about apple (I love most other things), they don't give uninstallers for software that's standard on their machines.

Comment: it just works :-D